# Exception in thread "main" com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamException:

Tags: java

I have written this java code for capturing photo through webcam, but this java code is throwing error/exception: Exception in thread "main" com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamException
Please help to fix it, I have added required APIs as well.

```
package photo1;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam;

public class capture {

    public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException {
        Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
        webcam.open();
        BufferedImage image = webcam.getImage();
        ImageIO.write(image, "JPG", new File("test.jpg"));
    }

}
```

error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamException: Cannot execute task
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDiscoveryService.getWebcams(WebcamDiscoveryService.java:124)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.getWebcams(Webcam.java:816)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.getDefault(Webcam.java:879)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.getDefault(Webcam.java:856)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.getDefault(Webcam.java:834)
    at photo1.capture.main(capture.java:12)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamException: Cannot execute task
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDiscoveryService.getWebcams(WebcamDiscoveryService.java:116)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamException: Cannot execute task
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamProcessor$AtomicProcessor.process(WebcamProcessor.java:72)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamProcessor.process(WebcamProcessor.java:140)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamTask.process(WebcamTask.java:46)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.buildin.WebcamDefaultDriver$WebcamNewGrabberTask.newGrabber(WebcamDefaultDriver.java:46)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.buildin.WebcamDefaultDriver.getDevices(WebcamDefaultDriver.java:118)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDiscoveryService$WebcamsDiscovery.call(WebcamDiscoveryService.java:36)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDiscoveryService$WebcamsDiscovery.call(WebcamDiscoveryService.java:26)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bridj/cpp/CPPObject
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.buildin.WebcamDefaultDriver$WebcamNewGrabberTask.handle(WebcamDefaultDriver.java:56)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamProcessor$AtomicProcessor.run(WebcamProcessor.java:81)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bridj.cpp.CPPObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: Does this look like your problem?  https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/issues/114

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a problem regarding dependencies. It says it can't find the `org.bridj.cpp.CPPObject` class.

Try to create a new Maven project and include the following dependency in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.sarxos</groupId>
  <artifactId>webcam-capture</artifactId>
  <version>0.3.10</version>
</dependency>
```